# Is it possible to locate a repository or entity from only the table name - symfony/doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Afternoon all, I have had a read over the docs in regards to this and I can not locate anything in regards to it so I believe It might make a sensible SO question.

I have bob.orm.yml:

```
BobBundle\Bob\Entity\Bob:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: BobBundle\Bob\Repository\BobRepository
  table: bob
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: '63'
```

I can:

- Inject that repository directly to a service.
- Call that repository via the container.
- I can call that repository via the entity manager(by providing the entity).

Can I call that repository by providing only the table value? Is there some wondrous entityManager->getRepositoryByTableName() or even getEntityByTableName() functionality?

Comment: Doctrine tries to abstract away the database.  So I don't think there is anything builtin that would let you look up stuff by 'bob'.  Might consider rethinking your design.  But if you feel you really need to do this then lookup Doctrine metadata.  The metadata contains all the mapping information so you could write a bit of code to search it on table name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Cerad. Its not the pattern I ended up utilising - I did look into it but it started to take me into a dark place. It _is_ possible using your suggestion but as you noted it needed a rethink.